# Dash Dropdown set max height

Tags: html, css, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm relatively new to Plotly Dash, but I've found an issue with auto resizing of my input box when I select multiple options on my Dash Dropdown element.

```html
html.Li(className="filter", children=[
    html.Div(children=[
        html.A(className="smoothscroll", children=["Kernels:"]),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            list_unique("KernelName", kernel_data, base_data), 
            multi=True, 
            value="ALL", 
            style={
                'width':'600px',
                'height': '34px'
            }
        )
    ])
]),
```

[image]

As soon as a few options are selected, the input box height grows too.

[image]

Is there a simple way to fix this? I've tried modifying my CSS styling, adding a `max-height` attribute, etc. and I haven't gotten anything to work. I'd like the height of this input box to stay fixed.

Comment: This is a feature actually (that is how it works). If you restrict the height, users won't be able to expand the dropdown to select/unselect options, unless you let it overflow via scrolling, which will bring another issue (because of the fixed width). You can try and see by yourself, just use `maxHeight` and `overflowY`. The reason of this behavior is that the option labels are so long that they can only stack vertically. To avoid this, one idea is to shorten the labels (eg. using abbreviations or acronyms), and use the "title" attribute so that the full label is displayed on hover.

Answer (score 0):

This css works for me:

```
.Select-multi-value-wrapper {
    height: 5em;  /* set your height here */
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}
```